# Event based triggers in AB testing using VWO

Tags: a-b-testing

Is it possible to create an AB test where 100% of users see a page and only those that click a button are entered into the variation in VWO (Visual Website Optimizer)?

I have asked the company but they often take a while to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding some code to the source:

```
window.VWO = window.VWO || [];
window.VWO.push(['activate', false, <array_of_campaign_ids>, true]);
```

Example : Triggering campaign 10 on button click

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function () {
    window.VWO = window.VWO || [];
    window.VWO.push(['activate', false, [10], true]);
});
```

Triggering multiple campaigns

```
$('#trigger').on('click', function () {
    window.VWO = window.VWO || [];
    window.VWO.push(['activate', false, [10,20,30], true]);
});
```

Then VWO has to set the key manual:true at their end which we would let them know when the test is built.